# Check if a character is inside a string via a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in Python. I am making a program where I take a input from user and check if any number is inside in the string. I am checking it by taking it in a variable. Is it not correct to check via a VARIABLE?

```
user_string=input("Enter the Word:")
print (user_string)
for index in (0,9):
    number=str(index)           #Typecasting Int to String 
    if number in user_string:   #Check if Number exist in the string
    print ("yes")
```

output:

```
Enter the Word:helo2
helo2
```

Comment: what do you want to do if there are digits?

Comment: Are you looking for specific digits, all digits, do you want to print yes every time you encounter a digit?

Comment: Any digit, as rightly highlighted by Daniel issue was in for loop. for number in range(10), works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string method `isdigit()` on each character in a generator expression within `any`. This will short-circuit upon finding the first numeric character (if one is present)

```
>>> user_string = 'helo2'
>>> any(i.isdigit() for i in user_string)
True

>>> user_string = 'hello'
>>> any(i.isdigit() for i in user_string)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at your for-loop. You are looping over a tuple `(0,9)`. So actually you are only testing for `0` and `9`. Use `range(10)` instead.

More elegant, to get the numbers inside your string, you can use sets:

```
import string
print 'yes' if set(string.digits).intersection(user_string) else 'no'
```